# How to get the total time a user is spending on an application

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I am well aware this question has been asked for vb.net however there is none for c# and I have been struggling with this code for about 3 weeks now and am stuck on this point.
I need to get the total duration of time a user has spent on an application. So far I have tried using appstart and append time spans however I get 00:00:00 I know why i am getting this result however I do not know how to solve my problem and I am at my wits end. So can anyone explain to me how one goes about calculating the total amount of time a window is open and saving that information all in real time.

```
DateTime appStart = new DateTime();
        DateTime appStart = new DateTime();
        TimeSpan Duration;
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        string time = now.ToString();
        const int nChars = 256;
        int handle = 0;
        StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);
        handle = GetForegroundWindow();

        if (GetWindowText(handle, Buff, nChars) > 0)
        {
            string strbuff = Buff.ToString();
            appstart = DateTime.Now();

            #region insert statement

            try
            {
                var with = cnSave;
                if (with.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    with.Close();
                with.ConnectionString = cnString;
                with.Open();
                string strQRY = "Insert Into [Log] values ('" + strbuff + "', '" + time + "', '" + Processing + "')";


                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strQRY, cnSave);
                try
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }

            }
            finally { }

            #endregion
            ActivityTimer.Start();
            Processing = "Working";
        }
```

This is not the full application nor is it what it looks like at the moment that is on a different PC and I havent uploaded that yet but this more or less sums up what the application does I run most of the codes from timers and well Like I said I am stuck.

The logic of what I am trying to do.

- An end user starts Notepad.
- my applications records the time that notepad is in focus or is the
  active window-
- end user opens or switches to a new application like Ms Words.
- my applications records the time that the user switched or closed notepad and calculates the difference between these two times and I get the total duration and save this information into a database.

and so on and so forth.

Comment: Is this a Windows Forms application?

Comment: Can you tell use why are you getting that result? Can you show us the implementation?

Comment: What do you meant by *get the total time a user is spending on an application* ? You mean how long it has been since user started the application? Or what ?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just record `DateTime.Now` when the user starts the application or loads a form you are interested in. Then, at any time you can just check the difference between current `DateTime.Now` and the recorded one to see how long they have been used it? This seems pretty obvious? Have I missed something?

So...

**AppStart or Form you are interested loads etc...**

```
Global.TimeStarted = DateTime.Now;

...
```

**Some arbitrary time or they close the app etc...**

```
var usingAppFor = DateTime.Now - Global.TimeStarted;
```

I have used `Global` but in your architecture store it somewhere it makes sense. You get the general idea though.

Comment: As alternative, that `Global.TimeStarted` can be a [`StopWatch`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/stopwatch) for more accurate measurement, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

As a base I'd use:

```
class SubscribedProgram
{
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan TotalTime { get; set; }
    public object LinkedProgram { get; set; }

    public SubscribedProgram(object linkedProgram)
    {
        this.LinkedProgram = linkedProgram;
    }

    public void programActivated()
    {
        this.StartTime = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public void programDeactivated()
    {
        // If this was the first deactivation, set totalTime
        if (this.TotalTime == TimeSpan.MinValue) { this.TotalTime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(this.StartTime); }

        // If this is not the first calculation, add older totalTime too
        else { this.TotalTime = this.TotalTime + (DateTime.Now.Subtract(this.StartTime)); }
    }
}
```

Then somehow you need to  monitor each followed programs "Activate" and "Deactivate"-events. Each time some of these events are triggered, you need to read the program, find the linked SubscribedProgram-object, and run it's corresponding method (like programActivated()).

Comment: I want to get the total running time for an active window not for my program

Comment: So do you want the total time the window Was Active? So if the user checks another window, the timer stops? And continues when the window is active again?

Comment: Yes but not for form windows for all windows

Comment: Then move the **"totalTime"**-variable, for example, to your **Program**-class: **public static TimeSpan totalTime;** , and use it instead: **Program.totalTime** . Then Add the events and **"startTime"**-variable I already posted in the answer to all windows you wish to follow.

Comment: Ok. Would this work for all windows "including" Microsoft word, Firefox and basically any application that has an interface of some sort? Because I seriously think you are misunderstanding the question

Comment: Then I'd create a new class, like "SubscribedApp". Add there the same 2 methods (activate and deactivate) and properties startTime and totalTime. And for each program the user wants to follow, a new "SubscribedApp"-object is created, which you need to link to the real program somehow. You need to run that object's activate and deactivate method's each time the linked program does those corresponding events.

Comment: Could you answer the question I asked you. Would this work for all windows applications,secondly I will not be doing any form of linking if you had read the question above you would know I am using the dll user32 and getforground as well as getwindowtext to acquire the window title my only problem is getting the duration of the active window and you're code to me looks like I would have to manually do all that which I do not want to do you're code also seems to work best inside the application it is linked to and not globally